# How do I create QDomNodes manually?

Tags: qt

I'm working on a Unit Test for a meta data loader, which takes a QDomNode and extracts the information into a std::map.
Now I have to create the QDomNode holding all the information i want to extract.
Normally this node is taken out of a xml-file, which is why I thought I might do it like this:

```
QDomNode metaNode()
{
  QDomDocument document;

  QByteArray metaArray(
    "<item name=\"author\">testManager</item>"
    "<item name=\"campaign\">testCampaign</item>"
    "<item name=\"comment\">testComment</item>"
    "<item name=\"date\">25.04.2013</item>"
    "<item name=\"description\">testDescription</item>"
    "<item name=\"projnum\">1</item>"
    "<item name=\"title\">test</item>");

  document.setContent(metaArray);
  QDomNode meta = document;

  return meta;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. When i call meta.childNodes() I'd expect a list of seven items, but only get the first one, holding the name "author" with the value "testManager";

Comment: That's not valid XML AFAIK. You need a toplevel "container" node.

Comment: Did you mean something like adding <metadata></metadata> (see update)?

Comment: Yes. Now that single child node (the root) should have all the right children.

Comment: Okay, so the list I want is meta.firstChild.childNodes() and not meta.childNodes(). Thanks for clearing that up, it works now. Will you answer the question then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after Mat pointed pointed out that I was missing a 'container' node, I tried that and made it work. 
This is the working code, which enables me to use the node just like it was read from an Xml-File (but without file-system dependencies):

```
QDomNode metaNode()
{
  QDomDocument document;

  QByteArray metaArray(
  "<metadata>"
    "<item name=\"author\">testManager</item>"
    "<item name=\"campaign\">testCampaign</item>"
    "<item name=\"comment\">testComment</item>"
    "<item name=\"date\">25.04.2013</item>"
    "<item name=\"description\">testDescription</item>"
    "<item name=\"projnum\">1</item>"
    "<item name=\"title\">test</item>"
  "</metadata>");

  document.setContent(metaArray);
  QDomNode meta = document;

  return meta;
}
```

Comment: FYI, that "container" node is typically called the "document element". In your example, `document.getDocumentElement().tagName()` would return "metadata".

Answer (score 0):

Using an actual test.xml file wouldn't make the test better? Since you actually want to test your code that takes a .xml file and returns a QMap i think it would be better to use a .xml file with the test too.

Comment: I don't want any filesystem dependencies, that's why I have to generate the 'files' we need at runtime. So actual files are not an option as long as it can be done another way.

Comment: Ok, you know better what you need, i just made a suggestion. 

In case you can't make QDomNode to work, QDomDocument class has some support for creation of in memory xml, see documentation here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdomdocument.html#details
//anyway i still think that the test.xml file is more relevant to the test (and also easy to setup)

Comment: Yeah, In-Memory-Xml is the approach I'm going for with the QDomNode. Anyway, I didn't mean to put your suggestion down. It's a valid approach, it just doesn't match my requirements.